# pygtk TextView and WebKit.WebView synchronized scrolling

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, pygtk

I've got a text view and a web view, each inside a scrolled window of their own and I'm trying to achieve synchronized scrolling between the two but I can't seem to get it to work.

The web view is basically taking the text from the text view and rendering it as marked up HTML via `webview.load_html_string()`. I think the problem could be the delay in loading the HTML as every time the web view is refreshed it is scrolled back to the very start.

Right now I call a function every time the content of the text view is changed and then modify the `vadjustment.value` of the scrolled window containing the web view.

But this doesn't work. Is it because of the delay? I can't think of any way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want sync those scrollbars? You can achieve this by using the same Gtk.Adjustment (number of pages sets to 0). 
I haven't use much of webkit but it essentialy a widget. so maybe a workaround would be disconnect a signal "value-changed" from Gtk.Adjustment until "load-status" signal from WebKitView reached Webkit.LoadStatus.FINISHED (if that's the correct syntax).
If that doesn't work, maybe you use WebKitView.move_cursor () (if i remember the function properly) based on Gtk.Adjustment on your text view (we use 2 adjustments this time)

Comment: I tried the second method, it sort of twitches. It scrolls to the point I specified but then jumps immediately back to the start/top. Is there a signal I should disconnect?